# How can I get a Zulu domination vic at Emperor level?

Tags: civilization-5

I have tried 2 tactics to get this vic: 1) going straight for S.Zeus and then to Civ. Service to build an Impi army (I won that way at a lower level), and 2) getting G.Library first and then S.Zeus and so on. In both cases I get outrun in tech by at least one other civ. If I destroy one of my neighbours, all the other civs gang up on me. What do you recommend in terms of policies, tech strategies and religious tenants to get to a domination vic at emperor level?

Comment: hmmm, I have found the best strategy for anything higher than prince is to go straight science. You won't be able to keep up so late game is usually when I shoot for attacking.

Answer (score 3):

You say you're destroying neighbor civ. Are you taking every city or just the capital? Each city you take will get you a warmonger bonus. Go Statue of Zeus, take the capitals of your two nearest neighbors, then hang back and build up science. Those two capitol cities will get you enough growth to jump ahead in science race and two cities won't get enough warmonger penalty to have everyone declare against you.

Comment: Thanks, vhgames. In my last game I took out the whole civ, largely because they had boxed me in on a peninsula. I'll try what you say about just taking the capitals, but what if they are are not next me? I mean, what if I need to defeat at least one other city just to get to an opponent's capital? That uses a lot of resources and while I'm building an army, I can't build science and another civ will get ahead on tech so when I am ready to fight them, I don't have the firepower I need...

Comment: The key is to be selective. Don't bother taking an opponent out completely. Yes, if another city is in the way take it to get to the capital. But the point is to not go around destroying all of their cities for no reason. A weakened neighbor is actually a boon for you. They will never pose a threat, yet their other cities will block off territory from stronger opponents. The civ whose capital you took can even become a trading partner.

Comment: Bottom line, be picky about which cities you conquer.

Comment: If you can get two rivals to fight and take cities, you can take those same cities later and liberate them to offset your warmonger penalties.